# Unix Shell Scripting - Add Extra Column In While Loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix, while-loop

I have a file `server.txt` containing different hostnames like:

```
hostname1.com
hostname2.com
```

My shell script `servers.sh` is written to get the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files from the list in `servers.txt` file.

I wish to add the hostname from which the entries came from in my final output file. My script looks something like below:

```
while read HOST ;
        do
           sshpass -p $password ssh -n $username@$HOST 'cat /etc/passwd'>>users.txt
           sshpass -p $password ssh -n $username@$HOST 'cat /etc/group'>>groups.txt
done < servers.txt
echo -e "UserName;UID;GID;HomeDir;Shell" > final_users.csv
cut -d: -f1,3,4,6,7 users.txt  | tr ':' ';'>> final_users.csv
echo -e "GroupName;GID;Members" > final_groups.csv
awk -F '[:,]' '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)print$1";"$3";"$i}' groups.txt >> final_groups.csv
```

The goal is to add another column in both `final_users.csv` and `final_groups.csv` like `hostname` so I can know which servers each entry came from.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
while read HOST ;
        do
           sshpass -p $password ssh -n $username@$HOST 'cat /etc/passwd'>>users.txt
           sshpass -p $password ssh -n $username@$HOST 'cat /etc/group'>>groups.txt
done < servers.txt
echo -e "UserName;UID;GID;HomeDir;Shell;Hostname" > final_users.csv
echo "`cut -d: -f1,3,4,6,7 users.txt  | tr ':' ';'`;$HOST">> final_users.csv
echo -e "GroupName;GID;Members;Hostname" > final_groups.csv
echo "`awk -F '[:,]' '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)print$1";"$3";"$i}' groups.txt`;$HOST" >> final_groups.csv
```

Comment: Doesn't add anything. How will it add the $HOST variable outside the while loop?

Comment: You are right. You can do it row by row, replace end of line with $HOST using sed or some bash-hacking using `paste` command.

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it:

```
while read HOST ;
        do
           sshpass -p $password ssh -n $username@$HOST 'cat /etc/passwd'>>users_1.txt
           while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line:"$HOST; done < users_1.txt >> users_2.txt
           sshpass -p $password ssh -n $username@$HOST 'cat /etc/group'>>groups_1.txt
           while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line:"$HOST; done < groups_1.txt >> groups_2.txt
done < servers.txt
echo -e "UserName;UID;GID;HomeDir;Shell;Hostname" > final_users.csv
cut -d: -f1,3,4,6,7,8 users_2.txt  | tr ':' ';'>> final_users.csv
echo -e "GroupName;GID;Members;Hostname" > final_groups.csv
awk -F'[:,]' -v OFS=';' '{for(i=4;i<NF;i++) print $1, $3, $i, $NF}' groups_2.txt >> final_groups.csv
```